# How to replace certain parts of text in text file?

Tags: python, string, replace, text-files

I need to read through every line in a text file and replace every line with the string "+44" in it with "0".. Basically replace "+44" with "0" but keep the rest of the line exact same

My code:

```
f = open("Pajanimals.txt",'r')

for line in f:
    if '+44' in line:
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in checking each line - just replace everything in one go:

```
path = 'Pajanimals.txt'
try:
    with open(path, 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read().replace('+44', '0')
except OSError as exception:
    print('ERROR: could not read file:')
    print('  %s' % exception)
else:
    with open(path, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/Programs/whatsapp/whatsapp.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = infile.read().replace('+44', '0')
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object

Comment: @DilsaajanDuggal. Looks like your using python3. I've edited my answer (you just need to use `r` and `w` instead of `rb` and `wb`).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) here:

```
for line in f:
    new_number = line.replace("+44", "0")
```

If you were doing something more complicated, I would probably recommend a regular expression, but your case is very simple.

The only thing to note here is that replace will **all** the instances it finds, so `"+44123+44"` would become `"01230"`, but there is a maxreplace argument you can use to limit it to the first instance:

```
line.replace("+44", "0", 1)
```

Would transform `"+44123+44"` to `"0123+44"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open('Pajanimals.txt','rt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open('Pajanimals.txt','wt')
f.writelines([line.replace('+44','0') for line in lines])
f.close()
```